# Writing a list of names, with a limited amount of "active" letters at a time. Algorithm to sort the names to reduce the amount of swapping letters?

Tags: algorithms

While making name-tags for a dinner seating, I stumbled upon a problem which I can't find any algorithm to solve, and I'm not sure where to begin.

The goal is to write the name of each dinner guest on a card, completing one name at a time.
The names are written with old-fashioned rubber stamps, so only 6 letters can be "active" at any given time. When a new letter is required, one of the active letters has to be swapped out for the new letter.

The problem is to sort the names in such an order, that I need to do the least amount of letter-swapping.

**Example** 
I want to write the names:

- Jack
- Julie
- Chuck

I can do this with 3 letter-swaps
**Initial letters:** J A C K H U
Write: Jack, Chuck

*{swap **A, C, K** with **L, I, E**}*

**New active letters:**
J L I E H U
Write: Julie

Now I want to find an algorithm that, given a list of names and a limit of active characters, provide the order of names and which letters to swap at each name, to reduce the total amount of letter-swaps.

Any ideas or pointers are welcome.

Comment: This can be thought of as a resource scheduling problem, somewhat similar to [job shop scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling). Many scheduling problems are NP-hard, but some admit polynomial time algorithms that provide approximations within a constant factor of optimal.

Comment: I did consider whether it would be NP-hard. Mostly, I've considered calculating a "letter-distance" for each name, and the finding the shortest route through the graph, but from there it would become a traveling salesman problem.

Comment: Assume you have a name ABCDEFGH. What of the following is true? 1) You write ABCDEF, switch letters, write GH. 2) You can't write this name at all.